# android NavigationView submenus aren't added if there are some items

Tags: android

Well, i liked an idea of NavigationView, but had bad experience with programmatically adding menu items & submenus

```
protected void inflateMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.addSubMenu(1, 2, 0, "Heading");
    menu.add(MAIN_GROUP_ID, 0, 0, "Something 2");
    menu.add(MAIN_GROUP_ID, 1, 0, "Title");

    menu.addSubMenu(1, 2, 0, "Sub Menu");
    menu.add(1, 3, 0, "Menu #1");

}
```

Sub menus isn't appearing on NavigationView, but if i remain just adding sub menus without any items, they appeared on the screen, so hence the question, how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in v23.0.0 of the support library so don't forget to remove the workarounds as soon as you update.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and solved it as follows:
You can notify the NavigationView that the data has changed by removing one item.

First adding an item and then deleting it afterwards does the trick for me.
Call the following line after you added the Menu:

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(mNavigationView.getMenu().add("").getItemId());
```

It's not nice but solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me as the "dummy" item doesn't get visually removed (support lib v22.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

Well, i found solution, we just need access to `NavigationMenuPresenter#updateMenuView(boolean)`, and call it right after population menu

```
/**
 * Tricky {@link NavigationView} doesn't allow create dynamic
 * menu, be clearly adding menu items on the fly doesn't updates
 * Menu Adapter in {@link NavigationView} so, to we should update
 * it manually view {@link NavigationMenuPresenter#updateMenuView(boolean)}
 *
 * Returns {@link NavigationMenuPresenter} instance from {@link NavigationView}
 */
static NavigationMenuPresenter getNavigationMenuPresenter(NavigationView view){
    try {
        Field presenterField = NavigationView.class.getDeclaredField("mPresenter");
        presenterField.setAccessible(true);
        return (NavigationMenuPresenter) presenterField.get(view);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: As with any internal method accessed by reflection, this could break with future releases of the package. :)