# How to add submenu items to NavigationView programmatically instead of menu xml

Tags: android, android-menu, android-design-library

I'm trying to add `submenu` items to `NavigationView` programmatically . I'm able to add items into `menu` but not into `submenu`

Adding items to menu works

```
Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, index, "Menu Item1");
```

But adding items to sub menu doesn't work

```
Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Sub menu title");
subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, index, "SubMenu Item1");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick to call [`BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on the underlying `Adapter` that contains the menu items. You could use reflection to grab the `ListView` or just loop over the [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) children until you reach it.

This isn't the most up-to-date code, as fas as I know Google hasn't pushed the most recent changes to the Support Library, but essentially [`NavigationMenuPresenter.prepareMenuItems`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L105) is called when you call `BaseAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged`.

But if you want to see the most recent source, you can download it through the SDK Manager. Choose **Sources for Android MNC**. Then navigate to

```
yourAndroidSDK/sources/android-MNC/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java
```

[image: sources]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        menu.add("Menu Item " + (i + 1));
    }
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("SubMenu Title");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        subMenu.add("SubMenu Item " + (i + 1));
    }
    for (int i = 0, count = mNavigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
        final View child = mNavigationView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
            final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
            final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
            final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
            wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

**Results**

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks it works. But it should be a simple way than getting the list view and refreshing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. And I imagine things like that will be a little smoother as the new design library progresses. Glad it works for you though.

Comment: What about adding submenu without a title? It's leaving space there! Might be an issue!

Answer (score 1):

Somebody figured out a way to do it via reflection and accessing a private field. It's not pretty, but it'll work, for the moment.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604299/4232051