# How to add an item to a menu group in NavigationView

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview, navigation-drawer

In a word game for Android I currently have a hardcoded menu inflated from `left_drawer_menu.xml` and consisting of 3 groups (my turn, opponent turn and finally other stuff):

[image: app screenshot]

```
mLeftDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mLeftDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
                Menu menu = mLeftDrawer.getMenu();

                if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.my_move) {
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.my_move, true, true);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.his_move, false, false);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.extras, false, false);
                } else if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.his_move) {
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.my_move, false, false);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.his_move, true, true);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.extras, false, false);
                } else if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.extras) {
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.my_move, false, false);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.his_move, false, false);
                    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.extras, true, true);
                }

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                mLeftItem = menuItem.getItemId();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mLeftItem == R.id.start) {
                            startNewGame();
                        } 
                    }
                },DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Now I am trying to change that menu dynamically.

I have SQLite instance containing all game data and use `IntentService` to read/write the database - that part works fine.

My current difficulty is: with the following code, the new items are added *outside* the `R.id.my_move` group:

```
if (mLeftItem == R.id.start) {
    startNewGame();

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(100);
    menu.add(R.id.my_move, i, i, "Item " + i);   // why is my_move ignored?
}
```

[image: app screenshot]

**UPDATE:**

As a further test I have tried assigning even and not even items to 2 separate groups with this code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(100);
int group = 1 + (i % 2); // can be 1 or 2
menu.add(group, i, i, "Item " + i);
```

However the result looks chaotic:

[image: app screenshot]

Also I have discovered the (probably already fixed?) [Issue 176300](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176300) and wonder if maybe sub-menus should be better used instead of menu groups?

Comment: Can you post your xml where you've defined your groups?

Comment: Thank you, here it is: https://gist.github.com/afarber/03408cf4d1e3f267589f

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609408/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-navigationview-programmatically-instead-of-menu-xml) may helps you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

On checking [MenuItemImpl](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl.java) source code

```
     ...
     *    @param group Item ordering grouping control. The item will be added after
     *            all other items whose order is <= this number, and before any
     *            that are larger than it. This can also be used to define
     *            groups of items for batch state changes. Normally use 0.
     ...

    MenuItemImpl(MenuBuilder menu, int group, int id, int categoryOrder, int ordering,
        CharSequence title, int showAsAction) {
```

So you should define ordering in your xml (give same order to items in one group and increment in each following group)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/my_move" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="0"
            android:id="@+id/game1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_stars_black_24dp"
            android:title="Game #1" />
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="0"
            android:id="@+id/game2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_stars_black_24dp"
            android:title="Game #2" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/his_move" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/game5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
            android:title="Game #5" />
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/game6"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
            android:title="Game #6" />
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/game7"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
            android:title="Game #7" />
    </group>
    .....

</menu>
```

and give an appropriate order value while adding the item in your code. So if you want to add the item at the end of first group, add it as:

```
menu.add(R.id.my_move, Menu.NONE, 0, "Item1");
```

and if you want to add to second group, add it as:

```
menu.add(R.id.his_move, Menu.NONE, 1, "Item2");
```

The problem with your code could be that all items in the xml have default orderInCategory 0 and so the new item gets added after
all these items.

**UPDATE**

To add icon use [`setIcon`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method for `MenuItem`

```
menu.add(R.id.my_move, Menu.NONE, 0, "Item1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_stars_black_24dp);
```

Comment: This works well and the colors are same too (when using submenus the highlight colors are different from the original menu). But I wonder, how to set the icon for the dynamically added menu entries?

Comment: Use `setIcon` method to set an icon, answer updated.

Comment: This seems kind of stupid.. you specify a group to add the item in, yet Android just ignores it and dumps it at the end of the list, unless you specify orders for items that are not even in the same group? What the hell Google? Also, it's still adding the item after the groups for me :/

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper Because of poor documentation I also did not know what 'groupId' means in  "..menu.add ( groupId : 1, itemId: 2,.......  Does it mean to add and generate a new group with this id we pass or as you say to add it to the group with this id in the menu we get?! 
But after testing it a bit now I know that groupId means the id of the group you are about to create and add NOT the one you wanna add it to! For that you can specify the group in a manner of indexing starting from 0 by eg: ...getMenu().getItem(index: 0) and then .add(groupId [the new group ID]

Answer (score 20):

[image]

I've solved it this way:

1. Set up the menu:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:title="my moves"
             android:id="@+id/submenu_1">
           <menu>
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/my_dummy_item_1"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                   android:title="Import" />
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/my_dummy_item_2"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                   android:title="Gallery" />
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/add_item"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                   android:title="Add Item" />
           </menu>
       </item>
       <item android:title="opponent's moves"
             android:id="@+id/submenu_2">
           <menu>
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/opponent_dummy_item_1"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                   android:title="Import" />
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/opponent_dummy_item_2"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                   android:title="Gallery" />
               <item
                   android:id="@+id/opponent_dummy_item_3"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                   android:title="Tools" />
           </menu>
       </item>
   </menu>
   ```
2. In `onNavigationItemSelected()`, get `MenuItem` you want to expand by order id (**or** via `findItem()`), then get `SubMenu` from it and add new item into it:

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.add_item) {
           Random r = new Random();
           int i = r.nextInt(100);
           MenuItem myMoveGroupItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
           // MenuItem myMoveGroupItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.submenu_1);  -- it also works!
           SubMenu subMenu = myMoveGroupItem.getSubMenu();
           subMenu.add("Item "+i);
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

I hope, it helps

Comment: Thanks +1 for the great answer. Do you know, how to add icon for sub-menu items? Also the highlight color seems to be different for those items...

Answer (score 2):

```
menu.add(R.id.my_move, i, i, "Item " + i);
```

You are also assigning the order (3rd param) as `i`. I am guessing that this is overriding the groupId. Try setting it as `NONE` as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
menu.add(R.id.my_move, i, NONE, "Item " + i);
```

**Edit:**
Maybe something like this

```
MenuItem lastItem = menu.findItem(R.id.<lastItemId>);
int lastOrder= lastItem.getOrder();
menu.add(R.id.my_move, i, lastOrder-5, "Item " + i);
```

`Order` is a combination of category and order, so it might not be as straight forward as this.

Comment: Unfortunately `Menu.NONE` does not fix the problem and menu items are still added at the bottom of the `NavigationView` menu - and not in the upmost group.

Comment: You could try calculating the required order based on items already in the menu and set that order.