# Android - App crashes when I add submenu

Tags: android

I tried to add a submenu on products and the app crashes on start. The problem comes from the submenu created. I dont understand why.

NavigationMenu.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home" />

        <item android:title="Products"
            android:id="@+id/nav_products">
            <menu>

                <item android:id="@+id/nav_tubeBendingMachines"
                    android:title="Tub" />

                <item android:id="@+id/nav_sectionBendingRolls"
                    android:title="Sect" />

            </menu>
         </item>


    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tube_data"
        android:title="Tube Data" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tool_setup"
        android:title="Tool Setup" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_mandrel"
        android:title="Mandrel" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_archive"
        android:title="Archive" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tool_notes"
        android:title="Tool Notes" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_converter"
        android:title="Converter" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_bend_guide"
        android:title="Bend Guide" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:title="Contact Us" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>


    </menu>
```

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Side menu
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
//button side menu
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

//toolbar
private Toolbar mToolbar;

//Fragments
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

NavigationView navigationView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //fragments transaction
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

    //select which fragment to show based on item id
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new SettingsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_contact:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new ContactUsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contact Us");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_tube_data:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new TubeDataFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tube Data");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_archive:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new ArchiveFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Archive");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_bend_guide:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new BendGuideFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bend Guide");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_mandrel:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new MandrelFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mandrel");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_tool_setup:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new ToolSetupFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tool Setup");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_products:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new ProductsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Products");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;





            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    }
//toggle para o menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

CRASH LOGS :

```
04-20 10:40:45.923 6040-6040/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android, PID: 6040
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuSeparatorItem cannot be cast to android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuTextItem
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.appendTransparentIconIfMissing(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:540)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:527)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:460)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:117)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:252)
04-20 10:40:45.923 6040-6040/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/AndroidRuntime:     
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:174)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
        ... 25 more
```

XXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXx

Comment: Please add crash logs

Comment: edited. check my edit

Comment: can you put your menu xml file with full code?

Comment: check my edit..

Comment: This error is not related to Adding menu item. It has to do something with Fragment inflating..

Comment: on which version android you are going to run?

Comment: i'm using API 25

Comment: If I remove the newly create submenu it works but I need the submenu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609408/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-navigationview-programmatically-instead-of-menu-xml

Comment: can you please give an image of your expected menu

Comment: Please see my answer below. I have added working xml code with explanation. hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38:`
>   `Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating clas`s
>   `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`
>
> Caused by:
>   `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error`
>   `inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

**REASON:**

The problem is in your `NavigationMenu.xml`. Item `nav_settings` causes the `InflateException`. This happened because this `item` has `icon` but the above `items` does not has `icons` and you have not `grouped` them together.

**SOLUTION:**

To solve this `InflateException`, put menu items `nav_tube_data` to `nav_contact` into a `group` and also you have to give an `id` to `group`.

**Here is the working XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item android:title="Products"
        android:id="@+id/nav_products">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_tubeBendingMachines"
                android:title="Tub" />

            <item android:id="@+id/nav_sectionBendingRolls"
                android:title="Sect" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="none"
        android:id="@+id/group_one">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_tube_data"
            android:title="Tube Data" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_tool_setup"
            android:title="Tool Setup" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_mandrel"
            android:title="Mandrel" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_archive"
            android:title="Archive" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_tool_notes"
            android:title="Tool Notes" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_converter"
            android:title="Converter" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_bend_guide"
            android:title="Bend Guide" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
            android:title="Contact Us" />
    </group>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>

</menu>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**One suggestion,** don't put your resource `icons` in `mipmap` folder. `mipmap` is only for `launcher` icons. For other `resource` icons you should use `drawable` folder.

**UPDATE:**

> I wanted to click `Products` and it goes to the page showing all the
>   items related to `Products`. There is no way to make Products `clickable`
>   like the other items like Home, etc...?

**Try this:**

```
    ..................
    .............................
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="none"
        android:id="@+id/group_two">

        <item android:title="Products"
            android:id="@+id/nav_products" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_tubeBendingMachines"
            android:title="Tub" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_sectionBendingRolls"
            android:title="Sect" />
    </group>
    ................
    .......................
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: @adiajdiadj If my answer seems usefule please give an upvote. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thank you for the help. My problem is that Product is not clickable anymore. Any idea why?

Comment: Product is a title not a menu

Comment: I wanted it to still be a item. For example i wanted to click Products and it goes to the page showing all the items related to Products. There is no way to make Products clickable like the other items like Home,etc...?

Comment: Ofcourse possible. give me some time. Do you want to keep divider between home and products?

Comment: Thank you. because like this it's also very confusing to understand that Products it's like a Main Folder and the others in the submenu are sub-folders. Am I also able to make Products bold and big text and the items on submenu normal and small text? Thanks

Comment: I accept your advice. I'm new in android programming. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to when I click the products the others will appear? otherwise my menu will be huge. :/