# How to use notifyDataSetChanged with the new NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, navigationview

I use the new `NavigationView` in one of my recent projects. However I have a problem for the update data.

Previously, I used a `ListView` in my `DrawerLayout` and when I needed to change my data I called `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of my Adapter.

Currently `NavigationView` does not `notifyDataSetChanged()` method and when I want to update an item on my menu nothing is happening, for example:

```
 Menu menuAccount = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_account).getSubMenu();
 menuAccount.findItem(R.id.drawer_item_login).setVisible(!isLoggedIn);
```

Do you have a solution ? Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Menu or MenuItem does not have "invalidate()" method so it should be updated right away, make sure you dont call setVisible() somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** This was fixed in v23.0.0 so you don't need to do anything by youself, just update your dependency. Got from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32181083/2489474

**Old solution** (just to see how stupid it could be):

But I've found working solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604299/2489474. It uses reflection to call updateMenuView(boolean) of NavigationView's presenter.

I've modified code from the answer for my purposes. Check also a method from the answer and choose which one is better for you.

```
//HACK
private void updateNavigationView() {
    try {
        Field presenterField = NavigationView.class.getDeclaredField("mPresenter");
        presenterField.setAccessible(true);
        ((NavigationMenuPresenter) presenterField.get(navigationView_)).updateMenuView(false);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

P.S. it is interesting that updateMenuView ignores a value was given to it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referencing group and then finding a item from that group and setting it's visibility **try to reference the item directly like this** ...

```
navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_login).setVisible(!isLoggedin);
navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_account).getSubMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_actions_user, !isLoggedin);
```

It works for me. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

@Moinkhan Thanks you for your helper but doesn't work for me. Here my menu_drawer.xml

```
<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/group1">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_publications_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_publications_24dp"
        android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_publications" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/drawer_group_account">

    <item
        android:title="@string/drawer_menu_sub_item_account"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_account">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_login_24dp"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_item_login"
                android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_login" />

            <group
                android:id="@+id/group_actions_user">

                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_add_publication_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_add_publication"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_add_publication" />

                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_my_publications_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_my_publications"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_my_publications" />

                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_edit_profil_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_edit_profil"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_edit_profil" />

                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_delete_account_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_delete_account"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_delete_account" />

                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_logout_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_logout"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_menu_item_logout" />

            </group>

        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

And my method to update my NavigationView

```
private void setUpNavigationDrawer()
{
    boolean isLoggedIn = sessionManager.isLoggedIn();

    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_account).getSubMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_login).setVisible(!isLoggedIn);
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_item_account).getSubMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_actions_user, isLoggedIn);
}
```

After some operations I called setUpNavigationDrawer() but the menu was not updated !

Comment: If the user not logged in then you want to hide all item related to accounts .?

Comment: "If the user not logged in then you want to hide all item related to accounts .?" Yes I would like this !

Comment: So for that just check my edited answer. Copy that two lines and remove it in your setup method . It will work ..

Comment: I have try my code to my side with true/false it's working. I think you have to debug the isLoggenIn variable..